# How to remove error created using cocos2d-x v2.2.3 (Language cpp) for windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to run my Game created using cocos2d-x-v2.2.3 (language cpp) for windows phone. But it shows following error.

**error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl StartScene::* )(void)' to 'cocos2d::extension::SEL_CCControlHandler'**

If I include pch.h file in all class file above error is removed then new error created. The error is
**"Cannot open include file: 'pch.h': No such file or directory"**

Though pch.h and pch.cpp are presented in CocosDenshion. In this circumstances what should i do?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

i think this because you use wrong function, fowllow this (CCObject::*SEL_CCControlHandler)(CCObject*, CCControlEvent) so the func you use must have func(CCObject*, CCControlEvent),